# React: hot update was not successful

Tags: reactjs, wso2, wso2-api-manager, react-hot-loader

I'm running my WSO2 source code with IntelliJ and this command: "npm start". But when I run devportal this error appears.
I change the node version, and also changed IDE. But this error still appears.

What is a solution for this error?

[image]

Comment: Can you try running "npm ci" first, and then do the "npm start"? If that also doesn't work, let's try after deleting the current "package-lock.json" file. Also, note that the node version should be 16+

Comment: Yes, first I ran "npm ci", and then "npm start". But as you told me, I deleted the "package-lock.json" file, and then  "npm ci" didn't run. And this error appeared: "npm ERR! The `npm ci` command can only install with an existing package-lock.json". again I ran "npm start" and that error appeared.

Comment: Let's try `npm i` after deleting the `package-lock.json`. Then, `npm start`. Btw, are you using the latest codebase? Or is this a specific API Manager version?

Comment: I'm using the latest version

Comment: I deleted the  package-lock.json  file, and then npm i. And again that error appeared.

Comment: is it not about timeout?  
@Ashera

Comment: Shall we try following this doc instead of the npm start approach https://tharanidk.medium.com/applying-ui-changes-in-wso2-api-manager-a6f1c1d70167

Comment: I think there is a problem with maven. What version shall I install?

Comment: Try with version 3.6.3

Comment: I Installed 3.6.3 but it didn't work. When I run mvn clean install, at the end of running this error appears: "File not found ('source//src//app//**//*.jsx')
    at module.exports (G:\WSO2\source-code-apim-apps-main\apim-apps-main\portals\devportal\src\main\webapp\node_modules\extract-react-intl-messages-compact\extractReactIntl.js:92:11)
    at async module.exports (G:\WSO2\source-code-apim-apps-main\apim-apps-main\portals\devportal\src\main\webapp\node_modules\extract-react-intl-messages-compact\index.js:95:25)
[ERROR] Command execution failed.

Comment: Can you confirm that the version being used is node 16, Java 11 and maven 3.6.3? If so try with a fresh clone or delete node_modules in the current clone and retry

Comment: Yes. Now I think there is a problem with userTheme.js and its configuration. The problem is that in the devportal path, there isn't any userTheme.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, there was a problem with userTheme.js. The problem was that, in the devportal path, there was userTheme.json instead of userTheme.js. I found userTheme.js from the API-Manager folder and copy instead of JSON and it worked.